# Disthinguish char and wchar_t in compile time

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have a template class simplestring which simplely handles TChar* and its length. TChar can be both char and wchar_t.
Here is a simple left trim method,

```
simplestring<T> ltrim(const T* _s = nullptr) const
{
    const T* s = _s;
    if (s == nullptr)
    {
#if ( sizeof(T) == 1)
        s = " \t\r\n";
#else
        s = L" \t\r\n";
#endif
    }
    constexpr int len = tstrlen(s);
    find_first_not_of(s, len);
}
```

I want s would be assigned a char* when T is char and otherwise be assigned a wchar_t*. It doesn't compile. PS: My project supports C++17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++17 you can use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If):

```
if constexpr (sizeof(T) == 1) // or (std::is_same_v<T, char>)
    s = " \t\r\n";
else
    s = L" \t\r\n";
```

Comment: My [mcve] adapted to your approach: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98c01fd294254689).

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option:

```
template<typename CharT> foo(CharT const* &r);

template<> foo(char const *&r) { r = " \t\r\n"; }
template<> foo(wchar_t const *&r) { r = L" \t\r\n"; }
```

Comment: I just think about whether simple function overloading (with type deducing in the call place) wouldn't be sufficient as well...

Answer (score 1):

With C++14, [**Variable templates**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) have been introduced.

So, using template specialization, it is possible to provide a variable with same name but different values for different types.

To illustrate a possible solutionh, I made the following MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
constexpr const T *init;

template <>
constexpr const char *init<char> = "string";

template <>
constexpr const wchar_t *init<wchar_t> = L"wstring";

template <typename T>
struct simplestring {
  const T *str;
  simplestring(const T *str = init<T>): str(str) { }
};

int main()
{
  simplestring<char> str;
  std::cout << "str: " << str.str << '\n';
  simplestring<wchar_t> wStr;
  std::wcout << "wStr: " << wStr.str << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
str: string
wStr: wstring
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa9a99314e5f529b)

---

The variable template as `static const` member of `template class simplestring`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct simplestring {
  static const T *init;
  const T *str;
  simplestring(const T *str = init): str(str) { }
};

template <>
const char *simplestring<char>::init = "string";

template <>
const wchar_t *simplestring<wchar_t>::init = L"wstring";

int main()
{
  simplestring<char> str;
  std::cout << "str: " << str.str << '\n';
  simplestring<wchar_t> wStr;
  std::wcout << "wStr: " << wStr.str << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
str: string
wStr: wstring
```

[**Life Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d8621e15726bac0)

Comment: Good idea! But, init can only be a global varible? Cann't be a member of the simplestring?

Comment: @Zhang I did a 2nd sample. However, the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61693356/7478597) is actually much closer to what you expected and more compact. (I was hoping that Evg will add it when seeing mine.) ;-)

Comment: I post both of your answers as a mixture answer. (I don't mean to steal your contributions :) I just think that is great.

Comment: Indeed, @Evg's is the most close to my orignal question. But yours I adopted in my code. It's hard to decide which one should be accepted as this question's answer. :(

Comment: @Zhang It was a fair competition and the choice is on you. However, if you consider Evg answers as closest to your expectation - I would support this. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Combined answers from Scheff and Evg, I made this one,

```
template<typename T>
struct simplestring
{
    static const T *default_trim;// = nullptr;

public:
    typedef std::basic_string<T> tstring;
    T* str = nullptr;
    unsigned int length = 0;

    void trim()
    {
        if constexpr(std::is_same<T, char>::value)
        {
            cout << "char";
            cout << default_trim;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "wchar_t";
            wcout << default_trim;
        }
    }
};

template<>
const char* simplestring<char>::default_trim = "hello \t\r\n";
template<>
const wchar_t* simplestring<wchar_t>::default_trim = L"hello \t\r\n";

void test()
{
    simplestring<char> s;
    s.trim();
    simplestring<wchar_t> s2;
    s2.trim();
}
```

Thanks to them!